# How to use find_package on a package added from top level add_subdirectory?

Tags: c++, build, cmake, static-libraries, target

This might be an x y problem, so here's my situation.

### Background

---

I have the following project structure:

```
-project
    -examples
        -example_that_uses_mylib_1
            * CMakeLists.txt
            * main.cpp
        -example_that_uses_mylib_2
            * CMakeLists.txt
            * main.cpp
    -external
        -notmylib_a
            * CMakeLists.txt
            * ... (other stuff)
        -notmylib_b
            * CMakeLists.txt
            * ... (other stuff)
    -src
        -mylib_stuff
            * file1.cpp
            * file1.h
        *CMakeLists.txt
    CMakeLists.txt
```

I'm attempting to make a cmake file that does the following:

- allows `mylib` to depend on targets in 3rd party libraries found in `external` with out using `add_subdirectory` given that they aren't actually sub directories and that is bad practice.
- allows `example_that_uses_mylib` executables that depend on `mylib` target with out adding it as a sub directory.

I was unsure of how to do this until I saw [this project](https://github.com/sunsided/cmake) whos top level cmake does this:

```
add_subdirectory(lib/foo)
add_subdirectory(src/bar)
add_subdirectory(src/baz)
```

and bar and baz `CMakeLists.txt` do this:

```
#Bar
find_package(foo 0.1.2 CONFIG REQUIRED)

#Baz
find_package(bar CONFIG REQUIRED)
```

Which made me think I could do the same with my libraries. I couldn't.

Originally the single top level CMakeLists.txt built all targets, I wanted to move away from this, and split up building with add_subdirectories, starting with `mylib`.

### Problem

---

Originally my top level CMakeLists.txt looked a lot like this (which previously worked):

```
add_subdirectory(external/notmylib_a)
add_library(mylib STATIC src/mylib_stuff/file1.cpp)
target_include_directories(mylib PUBLIC src/)
target_link_libraries(mylib PRIVATE notmylib_a::notmylib_a)
```

when I decided to split things up so originally I did this (which also works):

```
#CMakeLists.txt
add_subdirectory(external/notmylib_a)


#src/CMakeLists.txt
add_library(mylib STATIC src/mylib_stuff/file1.cpp)
target_include_directories(mylib PUBLIC src/)
target_link_libraries(mylib PRIVATE notmylib_a::notmylib_a)
```

Then to follow the other project I decided to do this:

```
#CMakeLists.txt
add_subdirectory(external/notmylib_a)


#src/CMakeLists.txt
find_package(notmylib_a CONFIG REQUIRED) #NEW LINE!!
add_library(mylib STATIC src/mylib_stuff/file1.cpp)
target_include_directories(mylib PUBLIC src/)
target_link_libraries(mylib PRIVATE notmylib_a::notmylib_a)
```

and I got an error in CMAKE

```
CMake Error at src/CMakeLists.txt:25 (find_package):
  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "notmylib_a"
  with any of the following names:

    notmylib_aConfig.cmake
    notmylib_a-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "notmylib_a" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "notmylib_a_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If
  "notmylib_a" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it
  has been installed.
```

How was the other project able to utilize `find_package` in such a way?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> How was the other project able to utilize `find_package` in such a way?

Config file for other `foo` project [has these lines](https://github.com/sunsided/cmake/blob/master/lib/foo/cmake/foo-config.cmake.in#L14):

```
if(NOT TARGET foo::foo)
    include("${foo_CMAKE_DIR}/foo-targets.cmake")
endif()
```

That is, when the `foo` is included with `add_subdirectory` approach and creates `foo::foo` target, `find_package(foo)` actually **ignores** its configuration file.

This is noted in the [foo's CMakeLists.txt](https://github.com/sunsided/cmake/blob/master/lib/foo/CMakeLists.txt#L56):

```
# We also add an alias definition so that we shadown
# the export namespace when using add_subdirectory() instead.
add_library(foo::foo ALIAS foo)
```

---

In other words, with given `foo` package included with `add_subdirectory` approach, using `find_package(foo)` is possible, but **optional**: One may directly use `foo` or `foo::foo` target without any `find_package()`.

Comment: Beware that the `foo` example project relies on `export(PACKAGE)`, which since CMake 3.15 is a no-op per default policy. https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/export.html#exporting-packages

Comment: @user7610: `export(PACKAGE)` is needed only for small part of the example. Configuration files are delivered also via `install(EXPORT)` mechanism, and that mechanism is usually implied when talk about `find_package`. Exporting of a build tree is a nice feature, but it is rarely used.

Answer (score 3):

The example project that you refer to is able to do:

```
#Bar
find_package(foo 0.1.2 CONFIG REQUIRED)

#Baz
find_package(bar CONFIG REQUIRED)
```

because both of the sub-projects `lib/foo` and `src/bar` have `CMakeLists.txt` files
that contain CMake code that generates a CMake package configuration file
that will be searched for by `find_package` when `CONFIG` mode is specified,
discovery of which will constitute success for the `find_package` command.

In `lib/foo/CMakeLists.txt`, for example, such code includes:

```
include(CMakePackageConfigHelpers)
...
set(PROJECT_CONFIG_FILE         "${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/foo-config.cmake")
...
configure_package_config_file(cmake/foo-config.cmake.in
        ${PROJECT_CONFIG_FILE}
        INSTALL_DESTINATION ${INSTALL_CONFIG_DIR})
```

As a result, when `cmake` is run to generate the project build files, the
package configuration file is among the files generated, like so:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/sunsided/cmake.git
...
$ cd cmake/
$ mkdir build
$ cd build
$ cmake ..
...
$ find -name '*-config.cmake'
./lib/foo/foo-config.cmake
./src/bar/bar-config.cmake
```

Those two `*-config.cmake` files are respectively the package configuration
files for `lib/foo` and `src/bar`. The documentation for [`find_package CONFIG` mode](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.14/command/find_package.html#id3)
describes the (complex) search algorithm by which `find_package` will discover them. For sub-project
`src/bar`,

```
find_package(foo 0.1.2 CONFIG REQUIRED)
```

is able to find `lib/foo/foo-config.cmake` because, when it runs, the build files
for its dependency `lib/foo` have already been generated. Likewise for sub-project
`src/baz`,

```
find_package(bar CONFIG REQUIRED)
```

succeeds because the build files for its dependency `src/bar` have already been
generated.

The CMake error that you receive from your own attempt to use `find_package` in the same way:

```
CMake Error at src/CMakeLists.txt:25 (find_package):
  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "notmylib_a"
  with any of the following names:

    notmylib_aConfig.cmake
    notmylib_a-config.cmake
    ...
```

now has an obvious meaning. To fix it, you need to fill in the missing
CMake code in the `external/notmylib_a/CMakeLists.txt` to generate `notmylib_a-config.cmake`.